# Turning off storage sense while mentioning 30 days under "Locally Available Cloud content"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, onedrive, storage

I am a bit confused on how storage sense work. For example in our case we have the storage sense turned off , but we can still specify the period under "Locally Available Cloud content", as follow:-

[image]

so will the "Locally Available Cloud content" turn the files not used for 30-days to online-only? or sense we disable Storage Sense then the setting under "Locally Available Cloud content" will not have any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files under “Locally Available Cloud content” will **not** be touched by Storage Sense if you have the setting set to **Off**.

The following settings only take effect when Storage Sense is turned on.